# Guarantee order of execution for HTML form submission and jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

Bare bones Example:

```
<form id="tForm">
   <input type="submit" id="tSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  $(document).on(   'click','#tSubmit', function(e) { someFunction(<fire-and-forget-action)});
</script>
```

Usage scenario:

1.) User clicks form Submit button

2.) someFunction( ) is called

3.) tForm is submitted as the default behavior of the HTML input element of type=submit.

Am I guaranteed that the someFunction( ) call will happen before the submission of tForm? There has been an issue raised that the possibility exists that the someFunction( ) call would not complete before tForm is submitted and a new page is rendered.

Comment: Yes, the function will complete.  The "click" event is fired *before* the default action of the button is carried out. Now, if the code in the "click" handler starts some asynchronous process (like a separate HTTP request), then *that* may not finish before the form submission completes.

Answer (score 0):

If the function `fire-and-forget-action` is an asycronous request then all bets are off.

You need to prevent the form submission (return false or call `preventDefault()` on the event argument) and execute it once the inner function has completed. You might, for example, have to refactor the 'fire and forget action' to do this, but without a big more information about what it contains, it's hard to help further.

Note that even then you have an issue where the form can be submitted in other ways. You're shadowing the submit click action, but there are other ways to submit the form. Ideally you'd observe the form submit event instead.

Here is a slight abstract example of how you should do it:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(e) {
    var f = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        f.submit();
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

The `setTimeout` is basically equivalent to some asynchronous request happening outside of the original handler. The point is, the inner function knows about the original form and submits it when complete.

Comment: The fire-and-forget function sends some tracking information to a 3rd party service. I will have to investigate and see how they are sending the tracking info. I think that it is a simple POST.

Comment: It's not really how they're sending it that you need to worry about, but how the response is handled. If you don't need to wait for the response (ie, sending the request is enough) then you should actually be ok - you don't need to hang around waiting for the response =D